# Apache Beam java Testing ExpectedLogs Maven

Tags: java, apache-beam, google-cloud-sdk

I'm using apache beam with Maven and in the pom.xml the dependency is

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
   <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I can use

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert;
```

but i can not use

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.ExpectedLogs;
```

like here https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunnerTest.java

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It is because `org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert` is in `beam-sdks-java-core` but `org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.ExpectedLogs` is in `beam-sdks-java-core-test`.

I don't think `org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.ExpectedLogs` is published into Beam maven artifacts. You can compile the module locally from https://github.com/apache/beam and add it to your maven project.

To compile `beam-sdks-java-core-test` locally, you first can `cd` to parent directory of Beam. Then run command `./gradlew :beam-sdks-java-core:shadowTestJar`. After that you should be able to find a jar named `beam-sdks-java-core-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar` in `sdks/java/core/build/libs`.